# Speeding up the iteration of a generator over a list

Tags: python

I have two functions found on the internet. Both are SieveOfEratosthenes, but one is a generator and one is a straight list creator. I'm seeing a speed difference though when iterating and am confused because the generator is faster in the event that you create the full list from it. I'm wondering if it's possible to iterate over the generator faster as it would be very beneficial to me as i'm trying to speed up some code. Here are the functions:

```
# Generator
def primes_sieve2(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False  

# Creates complete List
def SieveOfEratosthenes(n):  

   # Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize  
   #  all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will  
   # finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true.  
   prime = [True for i in range(n+1)]  
   p = 2 
   while (p * p <= n):  

       # If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime  
       if (prime[p] == True):  

           # Update all multiples of p  
           for i in range(p * p, n+1, p):  
               prime[i] = False 
       p += 1 

   size = 0 
   for p in range(2, n+1):  
     if prime[p]: 
       size+=1 

   #vv = np.zeros(size, dtype='int64') 
   vv = []
   count = 0  
   # Print all prime numbers  
   for p in range(2, n+1):  
       if prime[p]:  
           #vv[count] = p  
           vv.append(p)
           count+=1 
   return vv
```

Now, here are the timing differences, the generator is fast at creating the list, but slower when iterating over it, which is confusing me, so i thought i'd ask to see if i'm doing something wrong and to why this is the output. Here are the speed differences:

```
# The generator is slower at iteration

import time  
start = time.time()  
small_primes2 = primes_sieve2(10000000)
for xx in small_primes2:
   xx 
end = time.time()  
print(end-start) 
2.776512861251831

small_primes3 = SieveOfEratosthenes(10000000)

import time  
start = time.time()  
for xx in small_primes3:
   xx 
end = time.time()  
print(end-start) 
0.043845176696777344

# The generator is faster at creating the full list when not iterating.

import time  
start = time.time()  
small_primes3 = SieveOfEratosthenes(10000000)
end = time.time()  
print(end-start) 
3.6824228763580322

import time  
start = time.time()  
small_primes2 = list(primes_sieve2(10000000))
end = time.time()  
print(end-start) 
2.7591686248779297
```

You can see the generator creates the list in about a second faster, but is 2.3 seconds slower when iterating over it. Is this expected or am i doing something incorrectly?

I thought that since the generator could create the list faster than the non generator Sieve, that i could iterate over it faster but that is not the case.

Comment: It's expected since you aren't timing the work `SieveOfEratosthenes` needs to do to generate the primes. All you are timing is the iteration of a list. You'd get the same results if you iterated `range(10000000)`.

Comment: All you're doing in `for xx in small_primes3:` is iterating over a *pre-computed* list, `for xx in small_primes2:` has to generate a prime on every iteration

Comment: Ok, i get it now, my mistake. I see what's going on now. The generator is doing the work in real time during the iteration. Once again my mistake, thanks for claryfiing.

Comment: I was able to speed up my import by using small_primes = list(primes_sieve2(10000000))
 rather than the straight sieve by a second, so that's great. Once again thanks for the clarification, i don't know why i didn't catch that :-)